# Django template rendering HTML parameter as text

Tags: python, html, django

I created a Django template that requires parameters from a Django view. One of the parameters is a bit of html that displays a gantt chart.  Instead of rendering the parameter as proper html, it is rendering it as text.

Why is it treating the parameter contents as text instead of recognizing the `<script>` and `<div>` tags?

The html in the parameter I'm passing to the Django view looks like this:

```
        <script language="Javascript" type="text/javascript">
           window.onload = function() {
           var MyVar = [
            {label: "Label-less", times:[{"starting_time":1420228800000,"ending_time":1420257600000}, {"starting_time":1420264800000, "ending_time":1420293600000}, ]},
            ];

           function drawtimeline_MyVar() {
              var chart = d3.timeline()
              .showBorder()
              .stack() // toggles graph stacking
              ...
              *(code removed here for size purposes)*
              ...
             var svg = d3.select("#DIV_MyVar").append("svg").attr("width", 1000)
             .datum(MyVar).call(chart);
              }


        //Call the function
        drawtimeline_MyVar();
        }

       </script>

       <div>
           <h3>Mehe</h3>
           <div id="DIV_MyVar"></div>
       </div>
       <div id="DIV_MyVar_hover" class="hoverDiv">
           <div class="coloredDiv"></div>
              <table border=1 cellpadding=10>
                  <tr>
                    <td>
                      <p>Task ID: </p><div id="name"></div>
                    </td>
                  </tr>
              </table>

       </div>
```

And the parameter, **comm_request**, is used at the bottom of the template like this:

```
<html>

  <head>
    <title>Search Results</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script language="Javascript" type="text/javascript" src="./Review/d3-timeline-master/src/d3-timeline.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    {{ JSLIB }}
    </script>
    <STYLE type="text/css">
        .axis path,
        .axis line {
          fill: none;
          stroke: black;
          shape-rendering: crispEdges;
        }
        .axis text {
          font-family: sans-serif;
          font-size: 10px;
    </STYLE>

</head>

<body>
<div class="container">
    <div class="page-header">
        <h1>
            <p class="text-center">Much Results</p>
        </h1>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
    <h3><p class="text-center">Charts</p></h3>
</div>
<div class="container">
    <h4 class="text-center">
        Gantt Chart
    </h4>
</div>
{{ comm_requests }}
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In template, you could use `safe` filter.

```
{{ variable_with_html_tag_value | safe }}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to mark your html as safe, maybe using `django.utils.safestring.mark_safe` and passing your parameter as variable would solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the documentation of [safe filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.9/ref/templates/builtins/#safe). This is required to mark the string *safe*, that is safe to print as is without escaping any HTML. Note that when [`autoescape`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.9/ref/templates/builtins/#autoescape) is set to off, safe filter has no effect. With `autoescape` you can do what you need as follows:

```
{% autoescape off %}
    {{ body }}
{% endautoescape %}
```

This turns off automatically escaping of HTML, so that the contents of the variable `body` are output as is.